# What does "note of strain" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He transferred the Camels from his overcoat to a jacket pocket. **He wondered**, as he did so, **if they did not represent an unnecessary note of strain**. Mrs. Barrows smoked only Luckies. It was his idea to puff a few puffs on a Camel (after the rubbing-out), stub it out in the ashtray holding her lipstick-stained Luckies, and thus drag a small red herring across the trail.

What does "note of strain" mean?

What's more, may we say "drag a small red herring across the trail" equals "mislead others"?
[Context](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CGMQFjAF&url=http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm&ei=WogGU7CSN4rnoATCrYD4AQ&usg=AFQjCNF0BPhEl-n-I8N5KG-J8Fdlxg1fPA&sig2=nCbsqoRKdkmwuLzvItLdQQ)

Answer (score 2):

1) The sentences

> He transferred the Camels from his overcoat to a jacket pocket. He
>   wondered, as he did so, if they did not represent an unnecessary note
>   of strain.

may be paraphrased into

> He transferred the Camels from his overcoat to a jacket pocket. He
>   thought that maybe his decision to purchase the Camels was an excessive
>   step - **a sign (symptom) of his [mental strain](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mental-strain)** caused by the incessant thinking about the 
>   crime that he decided to commit.

Or, while on the surface the thought to 'drag a herring across the trail' may have been a clever one, on the other hand it may have been just a burst of unnecessary activity, springing more from his 'wound-up' condition than from cold-headed cunning.

2) You're spot on regarding the red herring bit.

Comment: +1 Pardon, what does "springing more from his 'wound-up' condition than from cold-headed cunning." mean?

Comment: Oh, it's simply my attempt to use complex words. (0: "Wound-up" means 'stressed, nervous'. He is nervous and so takes unnecessary steps: buys the cigarettes. "Springing" means 'originating from something'.

Comment: Thanks. to tell you the truth that would be gr8 if you rewrote your answer in simpler English just as happened about this sentence so that I could get it better.

Comment: You may pick some recondite passage from my answer and start a question, others will be happy to shed some light on the issue, or should I say stack and exchange some light. (0: